# Best solution for <div> shapes with content

Tags: html, css, web, shapes

what technique would you recommend me to get this shape in html and css? 
http://imageshack.com/a/img633/581/aPKAQp.png
I want to put text content in it. I also want to keep the site responsive (i'm using bootstrap framework). I thought about background-image, :before :after, or shaping div by border settings. I would like to know how others would solve this problem..

thx..

Comment: There are lots of tools and tutorials online. https://www.google.com/search?q=css+ribbon What have you tried?

Comment: thx, your answer was helping me a lot.. i didnt know that this kind of shapes are called "ribbons".. so you showed me the right keyword!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

http://codepen.io/thelifemgmt/pen/XbjNKg

```
<div class="banner banner--gold"></div>


.banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.banner:before, .banner:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #666;
  content: '';
}

.banner:before {
  left: -35px;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}

.banner:after {
  right: -35px;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}

.banner--gold {
  background-color: #cb9a31;
}

.banner--gold:before, .banner--gold:after {
  border-top-color: #9a6813;
  border-bottom-color: #9a6813;
}
```